# How to read not ASCII file?

Tags: java, encoding

I've got a txt file with cyrillic symbols. This is how I read:

```
        String csvFile = "C:\\Users\\dolgopolov.a\\Desktop\\Список рассылки 14 07 2014.txt";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = "\t";

        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
                String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                System.out.println("Номер: " + country[0]
                        + " , Сообщение: " + country[1] + "");

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

But the output is wierd:

```
Номер: 9047120386 , Сообщение: ��������� �������! �� ����� ����� ������� ������������� � ������� 2,98   ���., ������� ���������� �������� � ������� 3 ����
```

So, how can I avoid that? Do I have to change encoding  type or something?

Comment: Yes, you should set the encoding to UTF-8 and try again.

Comment: Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

Comment: It doesn't matter what characters a file has in it. You always have to know what character set and encoding where used to put them there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FileReader` uses the default encoding so you must use `InputStreamReader`

`new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), encoding)`

Comment: I've done this `br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(csvFile), "UTF-8"));`

Comment: Probably is the encoding... try "Cp1251" or "Cp866"

Answer (score 1):

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Unicode);

or

string converted = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(dataArray); where is dataArray your array of bytes

Comment: The question is tagged with [tag:java] and the code in the question is Java.